# JQuery set active link

Tags: jquery, css

i have a horizontal CSS Menu with this JQuery code:

```
function setActiveLink(target) {
        $(".MenuLink").removeClass("active");
        $('a[href=' + target + ']').addClass("active");
        //$('.tabcontent').addClass('hide');
        $(target).removeClass('hide');
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.MenuLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        document.location.hash = target;
        setActiveLink(target);
    });
    });
```

i want to set an active class on the clicked link (and remove all other active classes)

also, i want to be able to add the active class on the parent item when a sub menu item is clicked.

i tried creating the above function, but it doesnt add the class

i created a fiddle here with my full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/e79nz1cj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class first, then check if the currently clicked anchor has the class `MenuLink`, if not find the closest `MenuLink`, which isn't really a parent, but the previous element of the closest UL

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
        $(".MenuLink").removeClass("active");
        var link = $(this).hasClass('MenuLink') ? $(this) : $(this).closest('ul').prev();
        link.addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e79nz1cj/1/)

Comment: thats what i wanted - could you check here please - http://pastebin.com/KZzQ9Cbi i added the alert which is not showing, however if i add it above the document.ready function, the alert shows?

Comment: @Charles - That means you didn't add jQuery, you have to include jQuery before the script.

Comment: ah yes - its working now. although it seems to be adding the active class to the sub item, not the parent?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do that in the fiddle I posted ?

Comment: did you just change the jquery code? not the css or html?

Comment: And once again, you ***have to include jQuery*** -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5jkt9x5a/1/**

Comment: sorry - missed that one. i have in my own code though (<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
)

Comment: Then it should be working exactly as the fiddle, shouldn't it ?

Comment: thats what i thought.. but its not which is why i asked

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to include jQuery, if you want to use it. Did I understand you right? Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/e79nz1cj/4/)?

```
function setActiveLink(target) {
    $(".MenuLink").removeClass("active");
    target.addClass("active");
    //$('.tabcontent').addClass('hide');
    $(target).removeClass('hide');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.MenuLink').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var target = $(this).attr('href');
      document.location.hash = target;
      setActiveLink($(this));
  });
});
```